# I am getting error saying: Failed to execute plugin 'Cucumber Artifact Copier'

Tags: maven-3, bamboo

I am using Bamboo for building the maven project, And after successful build (BUILD SUCCESS) I got an error saying:

> **Failed to execute plugin 'Cucumber Artifact Copier' with error:
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.BuildContext.getRuntimeTaskContext()Lcom/atlassian/bamboo/task/RuntimeTaskContext;**
>
> AND
>
> **Failed to execute app 'Cucumber JIRA updater' with error:
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.resultsummary.ResultsSummary.getPlan()Lcom/atlassian/bamboo/plan/Plan;**

Can anyone please help me out of this ?

Answer (score 0):

The first error is often caused by incompatibilities with the Atlassian product (e.g. Bamboo) and the plugin.  "Cucumber Artifact Copier" is not listed in the official Atlassian Marketplace, and the only version that seems to still be used is for Bitbucket and is [having this same issue](https://bitbucket.org/vikasborse/cucumber-for-bamboo/issues/12/failed-to-execute-plugin-cucumber-artifact).  Again this is being caused by incompatibilities between the plugin and the version of Bamboo.

While not optimal, you can usually script whatever functionality the plugin was providing.  For example, use a "script task" to move the cucumber files to where you want to.  Your other option would be to find a supported plugin on the [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/) that accomplishes what you are trying to do.